# A url that can be accessed on chrome but not on OkHttp

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-glide, okhttp

example : [http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?S=%5Cpi%20r%5E2](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cdpi%7B220%7DS=%5Cpi%20r%5E2)

From this url (As well as other url under http://latex.codecogs.com which contains space, or "%20"), I can get a image showing "S = πr^2" on Chrome (both PC and mobile), but only get 400 bad request when I use OkHttp in my Android app. I tried various ways to solve it, but all failed. Then I tried to access it in the stock web browser in emulator, it get 400 bad request, too.

Why this url can be accessed in some browser but not in others? What do Chrome do with the url? How can I access the url in my Android app?

Thank in advance.

Comment: I suspect a User-Agent filter... can you try to mock it in OkHttp using a Chrome User-Agent ?

Comment: @Goufalite but url which doesn't contain space can be accessed successfully